# Make a 250 000 iteration loop more efficient to prevent freezing

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a macro/UserForm in Excel.

On a 15k row sheet, it takes about 10 minutes, while Excel appears to be frozen (not responding).
On a 250k row sheet, after 8 hours it never completed.

Is there a way to make it more efficient, or at least allow the user to view its progress without Excel being locked up?

**About the Macro**
Users are assigned tasks, and aren't supposed to be assigned the same one within 365 days. There are 47 Columns and 250k Rows of users. Rows are sorted by username, create date, task.
The macro goes row by row to first make sure its the same user, and then find instances of a task being asigned within the 365 day window, and flagging the row red. Then it checks the next row against the initial to make sure its also not within 365 days.

```vb
Sub highlight_newer_dates_v2()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim AccountNo As String, SpecialtyTo As String, CreateDate1 As Date, CreateDate2 As Date
    Dim lastNonRedRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    lastNonRedRow = 0

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        AccountNo = Cells(i, 9).Value
        SpecialtyTo = Cells(i, 13).Value
        CreateDate1 = Cells(i, 5).Value
        If Cells(i, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            If lastNonRedRow = 0 Then
                For j = i - 1 To 2 Step -1
                    If Cells(j, 9).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                        lastNonRedRow = j
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
            If lastNonRedRow <> 0 Then
                CreateDate1 = Cells(lastNonRedRow, 5).Value
            End If
        Else
            lastNonRedRow = i
        End If

        For j = i + 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(j, 9).Value = AccountNo And Cells(j, 13).Value = SpecialtyTo Then
                CreateDate2 = Cells(j, 5).Value
                If Abs(CreateDate2 - CreateDate1) <= 365 Then
                    If CreateDate2 > CreateDate1 Then
                        Rows(j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How many different usernames are there ? Does the entire row need to be coloured red

Comment: @CDP1802 Theres 250k rows and probably 80 different users.

User 1 gets assigned Task B on 1/1/2022, 6/6/2022, 10/10/2022, and 3/3/2023. The date 3/3/2023 shouldn't get flagged because it's outside the 365 day window of the 1/1/2022, but the other two dates should be flagged. It was difficult accounting for this.

The entire row should turn red on these instances.

Comment: @NickW First off, turn off `ScreenUpdating` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating

Comment: Second, progress bars are something you'll have to build via `UserForms`, check google. Alternatively, you can use the bottom bar in excel to be a progress bar.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Where should I drop Application.ScreenUpdating = Flase/True in my code block above?

Comment: @NickW turn off right away and back on at very end. I used to have an `init` and `exit` sub for my macros, depending on how many you have.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I appreciate the help on this. I'll have to read up on init, exit, and Application.ScreenUpdating, to figure out where to place them. I'm a rookie at macros. The one above took some time to get going.

Comment: How many years do the tasks span ? With that detail I can create a representative data set to test the performance of different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through row by row in vba is going to be inefficient. If I am understanding your problem correctly, you should  1. sort by date 2. sort by task 3 sort by user 4. use the formulas below. You would have to add even more columns if you might have more than 3 sequences, but its a pattern. You could also have vba sort by these values, put in the formulas, past the any true column as values and then sort back to your original order.

SEQUNCE

`=COUNTIFS($A$5:A5,A5,$B$5:B5,B5)`

2nd too close to 1st
`=IF(AND(D6=2,(C6-C5)<365),1,0)`

3rd too close to 2nd
`=IF(AND(D7=3,(C7-C6)<365,E6=0),1,0)`

ANY TRUE
`=MAX(E5:F5)`

[image]

Comment: We're sorting by User -> Task -> Create Date, but this was because the method we were using. The trouble was... lets say User 1 gets assigned Task B on 1/1/2022, 6/6/2022, 10/10/2022, and 3/3/2023. That date 3/3/2023 shouldn't get flagged because it's outside the 365 day window of the 1/1/2022, but the other two dates should be flagged. It was difficult accounting for this. Does this make sense?

Comment: Edited my answer to account for up to 3 sequences (you'd just have to add more columns following the same pattern for 4+ sequences). It might be messy to add more columns, but it will save you from having to loop vba by row. You could also combine those columns into one VERY long if statement, but i left it as 3 columns to show the pattern more easily.

Comment: @NickW In your question you said "Rows are sorted by username, create date, task."

Answer (score 0):

Process 15,000 rows in a few seconds, 250,000 in < 1 minute.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub highlight_newer_dates_v4()

    Const COLS = 47

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dictTask, k, colDates As Collection
    Dim bRed() As Boolean
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, r1 As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim dt As Date, dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    Dim task As String, accno As String
    Dim t0 As Single
    
    ' store task and dates for one account
    Set dictTask = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' specify your sheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Testdata")
    'Call testData(ws, 250000)
   
    ' process data sheet
    t0 = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim bRed(1 To lastrow)
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            accno = Trim(.Cells(r, 9)) 'I
            task = Trim(.Cells(r, 13)) 'M
            dt = CDate(.Cells(r, 5)) 'E
            
            ' store tasks in dictionary
            If Not dictTask.exists(task) Then
                dictTask.Add task, New Collection
                n = n + 1
            End If
            dictTask(task).Add Array(r, dt)
             
             ' is ths last task for person then check dates
            If (.Cells(r + 1, 9)) <> accno Then
                For Each k In dictTask
                    task = CStr(k)
                    Set colDates = dictTask(k)
                   
                    ' check interval for all permutations
                    ' is > 365 days
                    For i = 1 To colDates.Count - 1
                        r1 = colDates(i)(0)
                        dt1 = colDates(i)(1)
                        dt = DateAdd("d", 365, dt1)  '365 days later
                        If bRed(r1) = False Then
                            For j = i + 1 To colDates.Count
                                ' color rows red if <= 365
                                r2 = colDates(j)(0)
                                dt2 = colDates(j)(1)
                                If bRed(r2) = False And dt2 <= dt Then
                                    bRed(r2) = True
                                    '.Cells(r2, 1).Resize(, COLS).Interior.Color = vbRed
                                    .Cells(r2, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
                             
                ' clear data for next account
                dictTask.RemoveAll
                n = 0
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' result
    MsgBox Format(lastrow, "0,000") & " rows scanned in " _
         & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub

Sub testData(maxrow As Long, ws As Worksheet)
    Const USERS = 99
    Dim TaskCount As Long
    TaskCount = Int(maxrow / USERS)
    
    Dim n As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
        .Range("E1") = "Date"
        .Range("I1") = "AccNo"
        .Range("M1") = "Task"
    
        For n = 2 To maxrow
            .Cells(n, 5) = DateAdd("d", 1000 * Rnd(), DateSerial(2020, 1, 1))
            .Cells(n, 9) = "ID_" & Format(Rnd() * USERS + 1, "000")
            .Cells(n, 13) = "Task_" & Format(Rnd() * TaskCount + 1, "0000")
        Next
        .Columns.AutoFit
    
        ' sort username, create date, task
        With .Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add2 Key:=Range("I1:I" & maxrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add2 Key:=Range("E1:E" & maxrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add2 Key:=Range("M1:M" & maxrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            .SetRange Range("E1:M" & maxrow)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
    MsgBox Format(maxrow, "0,000") & " rows created in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```